# Can only connect to shares using FQDN

Tags: mac, dns

I'm trying to connect to one of my network shares using a Macbook Pro.

If I type smb://mysharealias.mycompany.com/users (which is an alias), I can view the share.  However, if I just type smb://mysharealias/users it says "There was a problem connecting to the server"

If I type smb://actualname.mycompany.com/users, I can connect as well.

It only seems to have this problem with some shares.  It works fine from all Windows machines and I've confirmed that all shares are configured the same way.

Is this a known issue with OSX?

Comment: You should add `mycompany.com` to the `Search Domain` in OSX.

Comment: mycompany.com is already in the search domain.  I can reach other servers fine, it seems to just be this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows machines are likely finding each other using NetBIOS broadcast queries.  They may even be using WINS servers for these "short names" (ipconfig /all will tell you).  OS X doesn't use that ancient technology.  Get used to FQDNs because they will work from anywhere.  The world isn't flat anymore.